# Hive:- how to extract data string from a given Attribute using regular expression

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have an attribute(column)in a hive table named as filename= **DataProgram**_**ModelYear**MY_PRISM_DEPSpec.csv for example 
data 1- GD391P_JIK_2019MY_PRISM_DEPSpec.csv data 2- T811P_2020MY_AA_DEPSpec.csv 
so in this i need to extract **DataProgram** and **ModelYear** i.e from
data 1- GD391P_JIK and 2019
data 2- T811P and 2020

Can regex extract help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
regexp_extract("filename=data 1- GD391P_JIK_2019MY_PRISM_DEPSpec.csv", 
 "filename=(.*)_(.*)MY",1)
```

Gives you `data 1- GD391P_JIK`

```
select 
regexp_extract("filename=data 1- GD391P_JIK_2019MY_PRISM_DEPSpec.csv", 
 "filename=(.*)_(.*)MY",2)
```

gives you `2019`